# Code coverage published to Sonar is not correct

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, jacoco-maven-plugin

We're using Sonar Server 9.1 and using maven command to publish reports to Sonar along with code coverage generated through Jacoco

In index.html file generated for code coverage, we can see code coverage as -   68% but used jacoco.xml file to publish to Sonar it's showing only 48.6% code coverages.

What analysis I should do to find the cause of discrepancy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonarqube overall coverage does not match jacoco report coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226859/sonarqube-overall-coverage-does-not-match-jacoco-report-coverage)